# How to install popper.js to use with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I want to use bootstrap locally, but I need the jquery.min.js and popper.min.js files for bootstrap to work ok. I don't see the popper file in the official page [enter link description here](https://popper.js.org)
I don't want to use CDN, I want it locally. Any idea to do this? Thank you.

Comment: You can just open the popper.js file in your browser and then save it as a file to use it locally.

Comment: Ok. I have the file, but I have this problem in the console now: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/smd-cell-60/application/views/tuscany/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE ---------------------
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/smd-cell-60/application/views/tuscany/resources/js/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded it from a CDN? It looks like you installed it as an npm package and downloaded it from there.

Comment: These ones were already in a folder that a friend sent me. I don't use npm, should I download the bootstrap files and eveything else again?

Comment: Yes, that would probably work.